# Visual C#, process keeps growing until I get memory errors relating to a UserControl using a loop to draw graphics

Tags: c#, loops, graphics, resources

Using Visual C# 2008 Exp Edition, I've noticed that with my project loaded the process is consuming ~70,000K of memory. After a few hours this builds up to about ~500,000K.

At this point a `UserControl` containing a `PictureBox` (within a `Panel`) shows a memory error in Visual C# Express. The picture box contains a bitmap and grid of rectangles, drawn with `System.Drawing.Graphics`.

Here's the code:

This segement occurs just once when the `UserControl` is initialised.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(a, b);
Graphics g = null;
g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.SteelBlue, 0, 0, c, d);

//Paint Rows & Columns
for (int x = 0; x <= e - 1; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= f - 1; y++)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, g, h, i);
    }
}
//Release Resources
g.Dispose();
//Add bitmap with grid to BG
ScorePictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
```

This piece of code is quite frequent:

```
for (int EventIndex = 0; EventIndex <= MidiNoteDownArray.Length - 1; EventIndex++)
{
    //Paint notes to grid

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, j, k, l, m);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Purple, o, p, q, r);
}
e.Dispose();
```

Am I not releasing resources properly? How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not releasing your bitmap. Depending on how often your code runs the garbage collector may not be able to keep up.

```
using (Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(a, b))
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap)) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= e - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= f - 1; y++) {
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, g, h, i);
        }
    }

    ScorePictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
}
```

You will want to check other parts of your code that use GDI for unreleased resources as well.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can accept it as the answer and that would suffice. :)

Comment: I declared the bitmap as a class variable  & it seems garbage collection is doing its job now :D thanks again.